# Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 IIS Express Basic authentication Logon failure

Tags: visual-studio-2012, basic-authentication, iis-express

We have a wizard for Visual Studio which generates new ASP.NET project with different settings, like authentication.

After installing "Update 2" for VS11 generated application gets 401.1 - Unauthorized when Basic authentication through HTTP is used. If I switch to Development Server instead of IIS Express, it works.

And one strange thing. Projects with Basic auth work with IIS Express from Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2012 Update 1. Version of IIS Express is the same - 8.0.8418.0.

Here are results of my debug attempts:

```
1. credentials prompt rises
2. I'm typing login and password
3. method IsAuthorizationPresent() should be called but this does not happen!
```

Method IsAuthorizationPresent() is called when Development Server is used.

```
public class BasicAuthenticationModule : AuthenticationModuleBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks whether authorization header is present.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">Instance of <see cref="HttpRequest"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>'true' if there's basic authentication header.</returns>
    protected override bool IsAuthorizationPresent(HttpRequest request)
    {
        string auth = request.Headers["Authorization"];
        return auth != null && auth.Substring(0, 5).ToLower() == "basic";
    }

...
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Update1: it was reproduced after restarting and the next day. But it is not reproduced on another machine and the same after 3 days.

Update2: it works 1-2 times and then doesn't work for several days.

Update3: here is response from fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="My Server"
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcdGFyYXNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXElUIEhpdFxXZWJEQVY...
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="localhost"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 19 Jul 2013 09:22:45 GMT
Content-Length: 1961
```

You can see two 'WWW-Authenticate' headers here.
Basic module is plugged in in web.config:

```
...
<add name="MyBasicAuthenticationModule" type="WebDAVServer.NtfsStorage.BasicAuthenticationModule, WebDAVServer.NtfsStorage" />
 </httpModules>
```